# Syncing several CSS3 animations

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I would need to able few css3 animations but I have been reading around and it seems it's not really easy. Is there any ways to do it with jQuery? Anyone have any experience on it?

Basically my html is this:

```
<div class="automobiles"></div>
<div class="airplanes"></div>
```

And both use same CSS keyframe animation. When page loads everything is perfectly ok, both animations are in sync, but at some point i will remove the airplanes div and then append it back. This point of course it might happen that the animations are not in sync anymore.

So basically is there anyways to sync animations with jQuery?

Thanks ever so much. I can attach css here too, but i believe its not really needed.

Comment: Please, attach the `CSS` and `jQuery` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to sync both animations at any given state - by that i mean that if you add "airplanes" back into the page while the "automobiles" animation is just half-done, well then you'ld be in trouble. Unless...

Here are a couple of workarounds:

1) put the animation into a class:

```
.im-animated { animation:customAnim 5s infinite; }
```

then toggle the class via jQuery onload and toggle it again when you add the airplanes back into the page. This way the animation will re-start for both airplanes and cars.

For instance:

```
var $autos = $('.automobiles'),
    $planes = $('.airplanes'),
    $both = $autos.add($planes),
    animClass = 'im-animated';

$(document).one('ready',function(){
    $both.addClass(animClass);
    /* ...more stuff happens here... */
    $planes.hide();
    /* ...more stuff happens here... */
    $both.removeClass(animClass).addClass(animClass).show();
});
```

2) Don't really hide .airplanes, instead move it offscreen:

```
$planes.css({'position':'absolute','left':'-9999px'});
```

so the animation will keep running. Then just `$planes.removeAttr('style');`, or put it back to its place another way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there currently is no API in JavaScript that allows you to control the animations I'm afraid.

The only thing we have is `animationStarted` which is an event that is fired when an animation has started (on supported browsers). Other than that we can't really re-sync animations, unless of course we re-trigger them somehow by, say, removing a class and adding it back again.

So your best bet would be to re-trigger all of the animations at the same time, or somehow determine when it is best to trigger you airplane animation (although there is no fool-proof way of doing this - the closes you can get is by timing your animations).

Also, just a thought, why do you remove the airplane div instead of hiding it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause CSS3 animations:

```
animation-play-state: paused
```

[CSS3 Animations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations&ei=zCiaUbvfOOzZ0QXp2oHQAg&usg=AFQjCNGh32LN-sBr4GlgkO6PPynUKBfmOg&sig2=5VIlwU2PjdLuuh-PF-ZL6w&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k)